# OpenGL: Aliasing of scrolling text

Tags: opengl

I'm making a newsticker with OpenGL. Characters are drawn using textured quads. The textures are created from bitmaps rendered with FreeType2.

The scrolling is done by calculating a `dx` based on the time passed and a given speed, and updating my "world x": `x += dx`. As I can't influence the time passed, `dx` has to take floating point values such as `0.5`.

Rounding to integers really doesn't work, it produces very noticeable jitters no matter what way you do it. I've tried rounding the "world x" value every iteration, staying float with "world x" but rounding the value given to `glTranslate2f`, using `GL_NEAREST` instead of `GL_LINEAR`. No matter what, at the smaller pixel sizes, there's always the unacceptable jitter, so rounding is not an option.

That means we have to render with floating point values and use antialiasing (Let's say `GL_LINEAR`). The problem is now that at the small pixel sizes the characters appear to grow and shrink, depending on what `abs(x - (int)x)` is: near to `0.5` or near to `0.0`. This growing and shrinking is perceivable as a sort of "edge flickering".

How can I make this perceived growing and shrinking go away? Maybe I have to dive into shaders and implement my own anti-aliasing algorithm? Any other ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You must implement some kind of subpixel rendering. You're scrolling in the X direction, so I suggest you render in the X dimension at, say 4 times of the target width (oversampling). Then in the fragment shader you perform a pixel coverage integration, i.e. you sum up all the texels covering a screen pixel and normalize (i.e. divide) by the oversampling factor. Depending on the output framebuffer format you may have to apply an gamma correction afterwards.

Comment: Are you sure this will prove better than the default antialiasing which I get with GL_LINEAR? I.e. when I draw a char at position `0.25` with GL_LINEAR, it's already drawn with `1/4` less black on the left side and `1/4` additional black on the right side (I hope you know what I mean). How does the oversampling method you suggested better than that?

Comment: @JoSo: The GL_LINEAR method will simply blur out the edges. If you look at this from the perspective of sampling, you got your text samples at a very specific phase. Now by scrolling the text you'd have to reconstruct a different phase of the original text, which however is not available. Oversampling provides that additional information to allow for clean, crisp text rendering with subpixel precision.

Comment: If we assume that my original sampling is already "perfect", then I assume oversampling shouldn't bring anything to the table, as it's only redundant information.

Comment: @JoSo: What gave you the impression that your original sampling was "perfect?" `GL_LINEAR` does not introduce any new information when it encounters a point that cannot be perfectly resolved; it uses a weighted average based on the distance of the sample point from the nearest texels. Ideal sampling would involve quantizing your text from a continuous function (e.g. using vector graphics instead of raster) rather than finding the nearest texel in a texture that already discretely sampled your font at a fixed frequency. If you're bored, you could read up on the Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: With "original sampling" the bitmap rendered by FreeType is meant. If the quest was to scroll *that*, no oversampling would help. But I will restructure my code a bit, and try it out.

Comment: I have now found that oversampling doesn't work. It makes the flimmering even faster. My problems seems to be Moiree effect. To minimize that, I'd have to reduce my physical pixel size instead of the char bitmaps. When I have the time, I will try to *under*sample.

Comment: @JoSo: That flimmering happens if you omit the pixel coverage integration step.

Answer (score 1):

Becuase you haven't provided ["small example"](http://sscce.org/) of your problem, it'll be kinda hard to figure what exactly is going on.

Anyway, possible causes:

In freetype offset to the next character is stored as fraction. If you're rendering characters like this (pseudocode)

```
float x = startX, y = startY;
for(c in charactersToRender){
    Glyph glyph = getGlyph(c);
    renderGlyphAtIntegerPos(round(x), round(y))
    x += glyph.advance;//advance is float.
}
```

individual letters will wobble back and forth when you shift text using small fractional steps. To prevent that, you'll have to calculate offset to the next letter as integer value.

```
float textStartX, textStartY;
int x = 0, y = 0;
for(c in charactersToRender){
    Glyph glyph = getGlyph(c);
    renderGlyphAtIntegerPos(x + round(textStartX), y + round(textStartY))
    x += round(glyph.advance);//advance is float.
}
```

When characters "grow and shrink" becuase of texture filter, it might help you if you

1. Render ENTIRE text string onto texture then scroll the texture.
2. Or Add 1 pixel border in all letter bitmaps, and render letters with border included (won't be possibel if bitmaps are non-transparent).

The reason is that if your letters are tightly packed, then pixels that are touching the border of the bitmap might end up being cut off with fractional sub-pixel offsets. Antialising MIGHT help with that, but that's not guaranteed. Adding border to bitmaps will prevent that, but you'll still need to enable texture filter.

This will improve text only if your glyph bitmaps have pixels that touch border of the bitmap. Otherwise there will be no effect.

And yes, writing a shader will help. However if I were you, I'd either used larger font or avoided fractional text offsets or wouldn't expect text rendered with fractional offsets to be readable.